How to transform @apply directives to classes when building tailwind-based component library?
I'm developing a React component library with styling based on Tailwind utility classes. I use tsup (esbuild-based bundler) to build it.
When I use inline classes everything works as expected:
// src/Demo.tsx
const Demo = () => { 
  return <div className="p-4 text-white bg-black">Demo Component</div>; 
};

builds to
// dist/index.js
var Demo = () => { 
  return /* @__PURE__ */ (0, import_jsx_runtime.jsx)("div", { className: "p-4 text-white bg-black", children: "Demo Component" }); 
};

and
/* dist/index.css */
/* lots of Tailwind variables */
.bg-black { 
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1; 
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)); 
} 
.p-4 { 
  padding: 1rem; 
} 
.text-white { 
  --tw-text-opacity: 1; 
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity)); 
}

Now this can be styled correctly by any browser.
However, I also want to use tailwind's @apply directive to extract some classnames from JSX and move it to scss modules:
import styles from "./styles.module.scss"; 
 
const Demo = () => { 
  return <div className={styles["demo"]}>Demo Component</div>; 
};

However, when built it leaves styles.module.scss as is:
/* src/components/Demo/styles.module.scss */ 
.demo { 
  @apply p-4 text-white bg-black; 
}

How do I transform it to something browser can understand?
